# Где хранить объекты, шейдеры итд

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, directx

У меня созрел вопрос: а где хранить все ресурсы игры (объекты, звуки, шейдеры), чтобы их невозможно было украсть? Например, у меня все ресурсы хранятся в папке `data/*`. Где * - подпапки со всеми данными. Если, например, поместить .obj можно просто в массив чаров, и обработать в движке, то .fbx просто не скопируешь и не обработаешь. Как это реализовывают другие разработчики? Куда они помещают все ресурсы?

Comment: Все, что есть — можно украсть. Вопрос не в том, можно украсть или нет, а в цене. Стóит оно того, чтобы прикладывать необходимые усилия, или нет.

Comment: @Harry тогда почему многие разработчики просто не могут оставить "голые" объекты в папке с самой игрой?

Comment: Чтобы увеличить необходимые усилия для кражи. Кроме того, это может быть как-то связано с удобством использования объектов в программе. Хотя не уверен в этом.

Comment: Чтобы повысить цену "украсть" и сделать кражу невыгодной. Кстати, вполне может быть использование каких-то внутренних форматов данных — удобных для разработчика. Может, ему, например, неудобно хранить изображения в JPEG'ах, чтобы их было удобнее воровать :)

Comment: Обычно ресурсы компонуют не с целью защиты от кражи, а в первую очередь с целью повышения удобства использования.

Comment: @user7860670 а какие цели удобства, например?